# What does 谁教 mean?

Tags: meaning

[围城](https://www.bookba8.cc/read-127977-chapter-8627301.html)

> 苏小姐面有得色道：“她跟方先生吃饭回来害肚子，这时候什么都吃不进。我只担心她别生了痢疾呢！” 那些全无心肝的男学生哈哈大笑，七嘴八舌道：“
> **谁教**她背了我们跟小方两口儿吃饭？”

Does it mean who did teach you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “ 谁教她背了我们跟小方两口儿吃饭？”

It's an old Chinese writing.  教 here means:

> 2. 使；命令; (let; ask;order)

> E.g. 他教我来找你.

Note: 教 and 叫 are probably interchangeable in this sense(let).